# Google Chart setAction: how to change TextStyle?

Tags: javascript, charts

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUfOR.png)
I am playing around with Google Chart (Pie), and I have a setAction like written below. This code adds a button on the tooltip. Does anyone knows how to change the textStyle of this button? It is not copying the format of the tooltip itself.

```js
chart.setAction({
  id: 'sample',
  text: 'Drill down',
  action: function() {
    selection = chart.getSelection();
    switch (selection[0].row) {
      case 0: alert('Downdrill A'); break;
      case 1: alert('Downdrill B'); break;
      case 2: alert('Downdrill C'); break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: are you getting error related to blocked request?

Comment: nope, it it showing the graph just fine (I have it now running in a separate html file)

Comment: What issue you figured out?

Comment: When I run my Chart, the font is quite ugly (too big for starters). So I want to adjust the font size and the fontname. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: So the font of the tooltip is OK, but the font of the button inside the tooltip isn't (the text: 'Drill down')